# zoo object cannot contain both factor and numeric vectors

Tags: r, zoo

I was reading the zoo FAQs, and came across something that I found surprising.

> A "zoo" object may be (1) a numeric vector, (2) a numeric matrix or
>   (3) a factor but may not contain both a numeric vector and factor.

Is it unreasonable to expect this to hold? And what are the reasons that this cannot be implemented in `zoo`? Basically, I would like to think of a `zoo` object as a dataframe with time ordering.

Comment: Any chance you can show us some code? Like, how you create a zoo object and how you would like to create one?

Comment: zoo was intended to generalize `"ts"` class in R to irregularly spaced series with arbitrary index class.  `"ts"` class is also based on matrices.  One of the reasons to stick to matrices is that operations on matrices in R are much faster than on data.frames.  If your non-numeric data represents IDs of some sort then they probably identify separate series anyways.  In that case, the `split=` arg in `read.zoo` handles that. Workarounds include separate objects for each class, converting factors to numeric (and maintaining the level information elsewhere) or using some other representation.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks Gabor. Your answer is exactly the kind of background I was looking for. If you make it an answer, I will mark it.

Comment: The background @G.Grothendieck provided is in the zoo vignette, [*zoo: An S3 Class and Methods for Indexed Totally Ordered Observations* (PDF)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo.pdf).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks. I have been reading all the zoo docs, since I anticipate using it extensively in an upcoming project. I will read the vignette as well.

Comment: @fgnu : If no-one else bothers, you're welcome to collect Gabor's comment and Josh Ulrich's documentation link and post them as an answer yourself, if there's information there that's not in any of the other answers (although it would be polite to wait a few hours and see if they want to do it themselves)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

zoo objects are a matrix with an index attribute.  Therefore, you cannot mix types in zoo for the same reason you cannot mix types in a matrix (i.e. a matrix is just a vector with a dim attribute and you can't mix types in a vector).

Comment: Beat me my ten seconds, but I win on verbosity ;-)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: you always win on verbosity.

Answer (score 4):

You write

> Basically, I would like to think of a zoo object as a dataframe with
>   time ordering.

and you are simply off-base here. "Wishing alone" does not make it so. In a nutshell, `zoo` and `xts` can cope with a numeric matrix (or vector as special case, both really are vectors with/without dimension attributes) and the factor is already a stretch.

For all the years that `zoo` existed, `data.frame` was never a supported data type and will never be due to internal architectural and implementation choices. Performance on `data.frame` objects is also worse.

But you could consider `data.table` as an alternative.

Comment: "Is it unreasonable to expect this to hold? And what are the reasons that this cannot be implemented in `zoo`?"

Comment: Yes there are.  But if you find a way, feel free to send a patch.

Comment: You are really original which is why it is your birthright to ask a question that has been asked a 100+ times on r-help, r-sig-finance, SO, ... and expect us all to jump in an repeat it all again, just for you as your are so special.  Matrix it is at the core of zoo (and xts).

Comment: Dirk, with all due respect, you chose to answer an unoriginal question. You could have left out all the irrelevant stuff and answered tersely, or even left a link in the commentspace. I guess I never saw the point of answering with animosity and disrespect, so characteristic of the R-list.

Comment: Dirk, didn't mean to dredge up an ancient question, but would it be right to say that what I asked in this question is exactly what the Python `pandas.DataFrame` provides with its mixed `dtypes` array, and the `index` attribute? Not meaning to rake up an argument, simply looking for your opinion to the extent that you might be familiar with the `pandas.DataFrame` object. Thanks, as always.